# pkg-config cannot find package on Windows with MSYS2

Tags: cmd, mingw-w64, msys2, pkg-config

I installed MSYS2 and inside the MSYS2 (MINGW64) shell I installed pkg-config and gtk4. When I ran the command

```
pkg-config --modversion gtk4
```

inside the MSYS2 shell, everything just worked fine. But as soon as I ran the exact same command inside a Windows shell, I got this error message:

```
Package gtk4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk4' found
```

I then tried fiddling around with the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable, but that did nothing. Then, I tried

```
where pkg-config
```

and got this:

```
d:\devkitPro\msys2\usr\bin\pkg-config.exe
D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\pkg-config.exe
```

Notice anything strange? Windows isn't running the same `pkg-config` that I was using with MSYS2 but is instead running devkitPro's installation.

Comment: M Qwadezo, I have removed some content from your **question**. If you would like to take that deleted content and recreate it in the answer area, it would be appreciated. We do not post solutions in the question itself, that is what the answer area is for. You could, given a short time, even choose your own solution as the accepted answer.

Comment: By default, MSYS2 ignores your system's PATH so I don't know how you got into this weird situation in the first place.  Also, when you say that you installed a package in MSYS2, you should make sure to specify the whole name so we really know what you're talking about (i.e. `mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk4`).

Answer (score -1):

**How to solve this**

Open up the editor for the PATH environment variable, then select the path that leads to the undesired pkg-config installation (aka the first line of the where-output). Click "Move down" repeatedly until you arrive at the very bottom. Click OK. Restart your terminal. Done.

Comment: As there are multiple build systems present on the system I's not very wise to add one of the to the system `PATH`. Changing it just for MSYS2 would be better. For example by adding `export PATH=$/d/devkitPro/msys2/usr/bin:$PATH` to `/etc/bash.bashrc`. But it should already be there (check it with `echo $PATH`)

Comment: What is the content of your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable when you call `pkg-config.exe`?
It should contain the location (ending with `lib/pkgconfig`) of the `gtk4.pc` file.